# Visio: import an excel table stored in an external website

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-visio, import

I would like to use a feature which is available in Excel. In Excel, you can import data from another excel workbook stored on a website. Excel manages credentials and everything needed for connecting to the website.

I was wondering if a similar feature exists in Visio. So far when I try to import an excel file located on a website in a classical way, it just returns an error.

Does someone know if such feature exists (or not)?

Comment: Which version of Excel? For those who don't know about it (including me), which menu gets you to this feature?

Comment: Latest version of excel (2016 I think). You go to Data -> From Web, you enter the URL and if the website requires credential, you can enter them and even choose the authentication type (Organization, Anonymous) etc...

Comment: Now I see it, Excel 2010 has this as well. Visio cannot do this.